# Possible bug filtering questions on mobile UI

Tags: bug, mobile-web

There is a bug in the questions page **present in all SE websites**. If I go to the questions page and click on a tag to filter for a subject and try to sort the questions by unanswered (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=unanswered ), when I move to the next questions page the sorting goes back to the original one (by votes). This might be related to the estate of the page, when I change the sorting to unanswered and the page gets reloaded I can see in the UI the sort hyperlink as "Votes".
I'm accessing the mobile website on my **Android device with Chrome**.

*------------UPDATE-------------*

As mentioned in the comments (thanks guys!), the functionality I'm referring to is the "Filter", and not the sorting.
The question still remains, if I apply a filter and try to move to the next page of questions, should the filter still be applied? (I believe it should)

*------------UPDATE 2-------------*

I've just checked the behaviour again and this is clearly a bug. The only option in the "Show" link that is not maintained when you go to another page is "Unanswered".
[image: Screen shot of option in page]

Comment: Unanswered isn't sorting criteria but an attribute filter. The sorting is chosen separately under the [More] menu.

Comment: On StackoverFlow click the "Filter" button then select "Sorted by Most frequent" and then "Apply filter." Then click the "Filter" button again to close the dialog.

Comment: Thanks guys, haven't released this summer is not the sorting. But the question remains, should the state of this filter be carried on when navigating between the pages or should it only be applied to the current page?

Comment: I've found that only the mobile-responsive site exhibits this behavior -- the full site keeps the filter on.

Comment: @WeatherVane The mobile site does not have a "Filter" button.

Comment: You're right, @Spencer the option In referring to in the mobile website is the "Show" link.

Comment: @IPValverde Yes, it does. And I see you've updated the question to reflect the nature of the bug better. You might also want to point out that this is a problem on all SE mobile sites, not just SO.